# make check fails to start in Postgres 8.4.2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, gnu-make, postgresql-8.4

I am running into a strange error when trying to run PostgreSQL 8.4.2's regression suite on a new Ubuntu instance that I've created on Amazon EC2.

I can configure PostgreSQL successfully:

```
$ ./configure
[ Output not shown ]
$ tail -1 config.log
configure: exit 0
```

It builds just fine:

```
$ make
[ Ouput clipped ]
All of PostgreSQL successfully made. Ready to install.
```

But when I try to run the regression suite, I receive an error:

```
$ make check
[ Ouput clipped ]
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/stock/postgresql-8.4.2/src/test/regress'
You must use GNU make to use Postgres.  It may be installed
on your system with the name 'gmake'.
```

However, I believe that I am running GNU Make:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

$ ls -l `which gmake`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Feb  6 17:41 /usr/bin/gmake -> /usr/bin/make
```

I see that in the `src/test/regress` directory, there is a Makefile:

```
$ cat src/test/regress/Makefile 
# The Postgres make files exploit features of GNU make that other makes
# do not have.  Because it is a common mistake for users to try to build
# Postgres with a different make, we have this make file that does nothing
# but tell the user to use GNU make.

# If the user were using GNU make now, this file would not get used because
# GNU make uses a make file named "GNUmakefile" in preference to "Makefile"
# if it exists.  Postgres is shipped with a "GNUmakefile".

all install clean check installcheck:
    @echo "You must use GNU make to use Postgres.  It may be installed"
    @echo "on your system with the name 'gmake'."
```

The comments in that Makefile indicate that there should be a file named `GNUmakefile` in that directory, but there is not:

```
$ ls src/test/regress/*akefile 
src/test/regress/Makefile
```

There is a GNUMakefile in the top-level directory:

```
$ ls *akefile
GNUmakefile  Makefile
```

Even when I force `make` and `make check` to use the `GNUmakefile`, via `-f GNUmakefile`, the same error occurs.

Note that I can run the regression suite just fine on my home machine.

Does any one have any ideas why it's not working on the EC2 instance?

**EDIT:** On my home machine, I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. The EC2 instance is running 13.10. Both machines are running make version 3.81.

Comment: The latest minor version in the 8.4 line is 8.4.19. And even then 8.4 will be EOL this summer.

Comment: Are you using the same Ubuntu version on your home machine as in Amazon ?

Comment: @Rico I've edited my question to contain this information.

Comment: I ran this on a Ubuntu 12.04 on EC2 instance and it runs great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have a messed up download or checkout.  There should be a `src/test/regress/GNUmakefile` there, as you suspected.  Try downloading again.

Comment: You are right, that file was simply missing for some reason. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is what that directory looks like on mine:

```
$ ls src/test/regress/*akefile
src/test/regress/GNUmakefile  src/test/regress/Makefile
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for your comment. That was my problem: just missing that file for whatever reason.